# Guest account unable to login when graphic logon disabled

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, login, login-screen

I have disabled graphic logon on my Windows 10 Pro PC so that users have to type in their username when logging on. This throws up an error when I try and log in on the guest account, though:

> The sign in method you're trying to use isn't allowed. For more info, contact your network administrator.

It works on the default and administrator accounts perfectly well. How do I fix the guest account so they can login?

Comment: What exactly is "graphic login" do you happen to mean picture login?

Comment: @Ramhound normally, when you log in, you have to click your username to select it. I have disabled the "show last name" option so that now the user has to type in their username instead.

Comment: [Guest accounts are broken in Windows 10](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/you-cant-enable-guest-account-windows-10-stop-trying)

Comment: This means the guest account is not delegated to access the computer you might need to add him to group users from local users and groups when you right click my computer and select manage

Comment: @Elie should I use lusrmgr.msc?

Comment: @DanielHarrin yes you can use that as well.

Comment: @Elie I added the Guest to the User group but it still isn't working

Comment: @DanielHarrin on the other hand you can run secpol.msc and navigate to : Local policies > User right Assignment > Allow logon locally . And add the user guest or the guest user to the policy .

Comment: Pls let me know your result after you done the step above.